# kotlin list group by with sort

Tags: java, android, kotlin

solution for solving list
group by price with sort by rank
my list is bellow

and I want a **output** like bellow response like  -

1. Rank 1 , price -5000
2. Rank 2-4 , price - 1000
3. Rank 5-8,price 500

please provide solution for that

````
  "rank": [
    {
      "id": 627,
      "group_id": 1,
      "rank": 1,
      "price": 5000,
      "status": true,
      "created_at": "2021-08-06T12:57:24.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-08-06T12:57:24.000000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 628,
      "group_id": 1,
      "rank": 2,
      "price": 1000,
      "status": true,
      "created_at": "2021-08-06T12:57:24.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-08-06T12:57:24.000000Z"
    }
  ]
}```
````

Comment: It's unclear what you want. You want a map of ranks by price key? Do the same prices always correspond with the same ranks?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to deserialize your Json to Kotlin Data Class, you can adapt following code...

```
data class InitialItem(val rank: Int, val price: Int)
data class FinalItem(val rankStart: Int?, val rankEnd: Int?, val price: Int)
    
val initialList = listOf(
  InitialItem(1, 5000),
  InitialItem(2, 1000),
  InitialItem(3, 1000),
  InitialItem(4, 1000),
  InitialItem(5, 500),
  InitialItem(6, 500),
  InitialItem(7, 500),
  InitialItem(8, 500)
)
    
val finalList = initialList
  .groupBy { it.price }
  .map { FinalItem(it.value.minOfOrNull { it.rank }, it.value.maxOfOrNull { it.rank }, it.key) }
  .sortedBy { it.rankStart }
```